# Ajax post to php page and insert

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When a link is clicked , I want the the name to be sent to a php page and that to be put into a database.

Currently I get a success message when the link is clicked and a popup that says Object object and not much else.

This is how my link looks :

```
<a onclick="save()" id="1" name="MyName">Button Name</a>
```

This is my Jquery :

```
function save() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/php",
        data: {
            name: 'name'
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function(succ) {
            alert(succ);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){        
    $Variable1 = $_POST['name'];
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `test`(`valueID`) VALUES ($Variable1)");
}
```

Comment: Replace `isset($_POST['save'])` with `isset($_POST['name'])`.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko no that doesnt work. The ajax still pops up object object and no data is sent.

Comment: You are getting `[Object object]` because, your response is an object. You will have to either use individual properties or try JSON.stringify(response)

Comment: By the way, what type is `valueID` column in your mysql? Is it varchar?

Comment: @SergeSeredenko Sorry it should be an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your PHP code as:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){        
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `test`(`valueID`) VALUES ('$name')");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>0));   
    }
}
```

**And in your Ajax Success:**

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response.status == 1){
        alert('success');
    }
    else{
        alert('failure');   
    }
},
.....
```

**Explanation:**

You are using response type json and not sending anything from PHP file.
You can send status from PHP in `json_encoded` form.

And than you can get both `success` or `failure` status in ajax response.

One more thing, from your & **@SergeSeredenko** comments, you need to use single quote for string value if `valueID` is string input.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

you can get value from `<a>` by using `data-attr` as:

```
<a onclick="save()" id="AncharID" data-myID="123" class="btn-large mcqtest">Button Name</a>
```

**In jQuery, use this:**

```
function save() {
    var id = $("#AncharID").attr("data-myID"); // getting from attr
    $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/php",
        data: {
            name: id
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.status == 1){
               alert('success');
            }
            else{
               alert('failure');   
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i get success , but nothing is actually inserting into the db

Comment: @JohnyChew: answer updated, use quotes around `$name`

Comment: First I thouht "how is it possible", but then realized you gotta do `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)`.

Comment: The thing being added should to the DB should be an INT . If i change the type in the db to varchar it just adds "name" to the db

Comment: @JohnyChew: alright, now which type r u using now, int or varchar??

Comment: name="Something"  The name is something . It will be numbers

Comment: what is the expected value for this query: **INSERT INTO `test`(`valueID`) VALUES ('???')** @JohnyChew

Comment: ok, if it will be numbers, than use name: '1' // any number, @JohnyChew

Comment: Okay if I had <a name="123">Link<a>  The expected value should be 123

Comment: @JohnyChew: ohh man, no you can not use like that in HTML Form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104176/discussion-between-devpro-and-johnychew).